# Sql Server 2005 Parameters VS Oracle Parameters

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am migrating oracle database to sql server 2005.

In oracle we used to have parameters in stored procedures like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WM_StoreMaster_GRID (
   SORTEXPRESSION           VARCHAR2,
   PAGEINDEX         IN OUT PLS_INTEGER)
IS
...
```

But in Sql Server can i use the parameters in the same way or is it mandatory to prefix all parameters with "@" sign?

i dont want to use @ prefix as it will require the web application to be re written to accomodate the changes.

Plz Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all parameters in SQL must be prefixed with @.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

> Variable names must begin with an at (@) sign

And, a parameter is really just an exposed variable.

Comment: Have been searching MSDN for the same but could not find anything specific. Plz let me know if u hit something. Im waiting...

Comment: @Deb Updated my answer. Now I am 100% on the requirements for @

Comment: OMG :(    ...Thanks anyway Justin

Comment: @Deb No problem, sorry about that. As always, upvotes and accepted answers (I think there is a 15 min time limit before you can accept, though) are always appreciated :)